# Counting number of binary trees with given node values and root

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, catalan-numbers

I came across following problem:

> Find number of binary trees possible with 2 as roots. Nodes={1,2,3,4,5}

There was no solution given. I knew number of binary trees for given preorder is given by Catalan number as $\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$, where $n$ is number of nodes. So does the above question same as asking: how many binary trees are possible for all preorders starting with 2? If yes, does the answer is $\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\times 4! = 336$ as there are $4!$ pre orderes starting with 2.

Comment: Well... you need to be careful about counting double. For instance $1\leftarrow 2\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 5$ will appear under *any* ordering that has $2$ as a root and $3\leq 4\leq 5$.

Comment: Did not get you. What is it with $\leq$? Its not Binary Search Tree but Binary Tree.

Comment: You can construct a lot of trees from the same pre-order, but the other way around is also true. I.e., two different trees might respect the same pre-order.

Comment: Yes that is true. The two sentences in your last comment mean the same, specifically relation of number of trees to corresponding pre order is $k:1$ and that $k$ is given by $\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$. But I want to know for count of binary trees with 2 as a root, is it correct to multiply above count by $(n-1)!=4!$? I am not able to conclude from your comments.

Comment: The two sentences do *not* mean the same thing.  You're saying that, for a given ordering, there are always exactly $k$ trees respecting it. I'm saying, for a given tree, sometimes, there is more than one ordering it respects. Take for instance the tree from my first comment. It corresponds to $4$ different orderings (by choosing the position of $1$). Thus, multiplying your Catalan number by $4!$, you will have counted above tree four times.

Comment: I tried to put my point in image [here](https://i.postimg.cc/T1VjryVb/treecount.jpg). Can you have a look at it once?

Comment: There are only three binary trees with $1$ as a root. $2\leftarrow 1\rightarrow 3,$ $1\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 3$ and $1\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 2$.

Comment: For instance, in line $1$, all four trees after the first are the same tree.

Comment: I didnt get why you are saying those four trees after first one are same. They are clearly different at least visually. Also, [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/55686/113697) answer says Catalan number counts number of binary trees (with specific pre order or post order) on given set of nodes. Same is stated on [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-binary-trees-for-given-preorder-sequence-length/) page.